# View is getting replaced while Scrolling in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am an Android Developer and very new to iOS App Development. I am trying to build a simple chat system with only one line of data in each cell.

I am using a custom `UIView` class to generate a bubble and a `UILabel` and an `UIImageView` programmatically.

When I run the app for the first time, everything looks good. Please see the image below:

[image]

But, the problem occurs when I scroll the `UITableView` Upwards and I don't understand why the bubbles shift themselves towards the right side. See the image below:

[image]

Some post in SO said that it is one of the feature of `UITableView`.

How should I solve this?

If you need any code snippets from any part of the App, please comment below.

**PS:** I am using Xcode 9 and iOS 11.4 as testing device and Swift 4 programming.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Below is `BubbleView` Class:

**EDIT**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class BubbleView: UIView {

    var incomingColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
    var outgoingColor = UIColor(red: 0.09, green: 0.54, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

    var isIncoming: Bool = false

    init(isIncoming: Bool) {
        self.isIncoming = isIncoming
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds);
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let width = rect.width
        let height = rect.height

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

        if self.isIncoming == true {
            bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 22, y: height))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - 17, y: height))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height - 17), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width - 7.61, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width, y: height - 7.61))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 17))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width - 17, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width, y: 7.61), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width - 7.61, y: 0))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 21, y: 0))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 4, y: 17), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 11.61, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 4, y: 7.61))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 4, y: height - 11))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 4, y: height - 1), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -0.05, y: height - 0.01))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 11.04, y: height - 4.04), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 4.07, y: height + 0.43), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 8.16, y: height - 1.06))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 22, y: height), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 16, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 19, y: height))

            incomingColor.setFill()

        } else {
            bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: width - 22, y: height))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 17, y: height))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height - 17), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 7.61, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height - 7.61))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 17))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 17, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 7.61), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 7.61, y: 0))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - 21, y: 0))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: 17), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width - 11.61, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: 7.61))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: height - 11))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: height - 1), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width + 0.05, y: height - 0.01))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width - 11.04, y: height - 4.04), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width - 4.07, y: height + 0.43), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width - 8.16, y: height - 1.06))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width - 22, y: height), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width - 16, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width - 19, y: height))

            outgoingColor.setFill()
        }

        bezierPath.close()
        bezierPath.fill()
    }

}
```

And, The tableView thingy:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BiddingHistoryIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! BiddingHistoryTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row

    var strNew: [String] = splitString[row].components(separatedBy: "-")
    let strFirst = strNew[0].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let strSecond = strNew[1].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if !strFirst.elementsEqual(VendorLoginSetterGetter.strName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)) {

        let text = strSecond
        let label =  UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        label.textColor = .black
        label.text = text

        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: 0.66 * cell.frame.width,
                                    height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = text.boundingRect(with: constraintRect,
                                            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                            attributes: [.font: label.font],
                                            context: nil)
        label.frame.size = CGSize(width: ceil(boundingBox.width),
                                    height: ceil(boundingBox.height))

        let bubbleSize = CGSize(width: label.frame.width + 28,
                                height: label.frame.height + 20)

        let bubbleView = BubbleView(isIncoming: true)
        bubbleView.frame.size = bubbleSize
        bubbleView.backgroundColor = .clear

        //bubbleView.center = cell.center
        bubbleView.frame.origin.y = (cell.frame.size.height / 2) - 20
        bubbleView.frame.origin.x = 50
        cell.addSubview(bubbleView)

        label.center = bubbleView.center
        cell.addSubview(label)

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ic_vendor_black.png")
        imageView.frame.origin.y = (cell.frame.size.height / 2) - 15
        cell.addSubview(imageView)

    }
    else {

        let text = strSecond
        let label =  UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.text = text

        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: 0.66 * cell.frame.width,
                                    height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = text.boundingRect(with: constraintRect,
                                            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                            attributes: [.font: label.font],
                                            context: nil)
        label.frame.size = CGSize(width: ceil(boundingBox.width),
                                  height: ceil(boundingBox.height))

        let bubbleSize = CGSize(width: label.frame.width + 28,
                                height: label.frame.height + 20)

        let bubbleView = BubbleView(isIncoming: false)
        bubbleView.frame.size = bubbleSize
        bubbleView.backgroundColor = .clear

        //bubbleView.center = cell.center
        bubbleView.frame.origin.y = (cell.frame.size.height / 2) - 20
        bubbleView.frame.origin.x = cell.frame.size.width - 200
        cell.addSubview(bubbleView)

        label.center = bubbleView.center
        cell.addSubview(label)

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 28, height: 28))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ic_user_black.png")
        imageView.frame.origin.y = (cell.frame.size.height / 2) - 15
        imageView.frame.origin.x = cell.frame.size.width - 8
        cell.addSubview(imageView)

    }
    return cell
}
```

Code Updated as Requested.

Comment: This is likely an issue with your row reuse strategy, though it looks like it may also be related to duplicate data. Does the same issue occur when you have 5 different numbers instead of three `580` numbers? You'll need to provide some more information about how you're creating and populating each cell.

Comment: It looks to me like when a cell is being reused, you might be adding another UILabel and UIImageView, rather than changing the text of the one that's already there. See how you've got a second label added on top of the old one in two of the cells in your example? If you could post your UITableViewDataSource implementation, I'm sure someone can help.

Comment: Can you show your class with the tableview?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yes, it does come when the numbers are different too. I'm pasting the entire Bubble Class code in my Post.

Comment: @PeteMorris Your answer makes sense. I am adding a View every time a new data comes in from the server. I'll post the Code.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Sure.

Comment: I might be doing a mistake by adding a new Label and Image as and when data comes in, but, Why does it shift towards the right. The first View doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your code that adds the subviews to the cell from the `cellForRowAt` delegate to inside their respective cell classes.

The problem right now like @PeteMorris said, is that your cells which will be reused will *already* have the subviews which you added when it was dequeued the first time. So whenever the same cell is dequeued, subviews are added to it *again*.

- The *elegant* solution would be to move the code that sets up the view to inside your cell class.
- If you are looking for a **hotfix** you could remove all the subviews from the cell in `prepareForReuse`. (This method is called every time your cell is reused before dequeue-ing)

Your reuse method would look like this. (This method is inside your cell class)

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    for view in subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, Okay, Will the problem of shifting to the right when scrolling upwards is also because of this.. and with this solution, that will be solved too.?

Comment: @UmangBurman i haven't checked your frame math. But if it sets itself properly the first time, moving the code to the cell should fix it. However i urge you to explore autolayout for positioning views as they are more flexible than frames.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer and explaination :) I'll try this, Well, I'm out at the moment so cannot try it out right now.. But, I'll upvote for the support. Thank you once again. :)

Comment: I does fixed my doubling of Views but the shifting problem still persists.. :(

Comment: @UmangBurman this shouldn't be hard. Just keep a breakpoint where you set the frame and check it's value.

Comment: But, Why does it shift anyway.? I'll check via breakpoint now.

Comment: I figured it out, On Scrolling, the `cellForRowAt` is called again.

Comment: @UmangBurman yes i explained this in my answer already. Which is why you should be moving your frame code to inside the cell, so that frame calculations happen only once.

Comment: You mean Frame calculation code in Cell class and cell assignment code in TableViewController class?

Comment: @UmangBurman yes only giving data to your cell part should be handled in cellForRowAt. Unless cells have dynamic layout based on data.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know that. Thank you. Lemme try it.

Comment: But my Views are created, frames are added so how will I move to cell class as I the next code says, cell.addSubViews(myView) ?

Comment: @UmangBurman you should move everything that involves view set up to the cell.

Comment: Okay, Shall I add self.addSubViews() method also inside the cell class

Comment: I accepted your answer because you are right in both the mentioned ways. Although I'm not able to do it properly. Thanks for all the help and support. :)